# Changable favicon based on post-featured image

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, favicon

its possible use to change the favicon on based the post-featured image icon?
I use 100x100 size or 64x64 icon images on my posts. I want these icons to show as a favicon also. if some posts not have featured images then show our default favicon. help me out how to this work through ad-filter or ad-action.

Comment: From what I know, while this COULD be done, it's not a good idea and it'd probably be unreliable because most browsers put heavy caching on favicons.  But, basically, what you'd want to do is just add the favicon code with paths to the images with the `wp_head` action.  But, how are you going to get WP to auto-generate all the different required favicon files when you upload featured images?  Like the `featured-image-favicon.ico`?  And I think that the `apple-touch-icon.png` has to always be named `apple-touch-icon.png` - so you may not be able to do this properly for all platforms/browsers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `wp_head` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) to print code in the `<head>` block of each document. If your theme does not use [the `wp_head()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/), then dropping `do_action( 'wp_head' )` into your `<head>` block is required.

Simplest way would be to wrap the favicon's URL in a filter, and then change that depending on the current post being viewed. Note you'll likely need to take measures to prevent caching of the favicon, which in my experience can be a challenge.